# Count in 'in' SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-in

I have a problem with:

```
select  UsersInfo.fName 'نام', UsersInfo.lName 'نام خانوادگی' 
from UsersInfo 
where UsersInfo.MemberID in (
    select COUNT(ToLend.UserID), ToLend.UserID  'تعداد کتاب های قرض گرفته'  
    from ToLend
    inner join UsersInfo on ToLend.UserID = UsersInfo.MemberID
    group by UserID
    having count(UserID) > 2
)
```

Error is:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

In this code, how can "count" for UserID?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sample data and desired results would help clarifying your question.

Comment: When you use `IN` and a subquery the subquery should return only single column EG: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID2 FROM TABLE2)`

Comment: Remove the `COUNT(ToLend.UserID), `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which user is lended > 2, you can remove COUNT(ToLend.UserID) in subquery. And if you want to know how many times is lended you can add subquery in select

```
select  UsersInfo.fName 'نام', 
        UsersInfo.lName 'نام خانوادگی',
        (select COUNT(UserID)
         from ToLend
         where UserID = UsersInfo.MemberID
         group by UserID
         having count(UserID) > 2) 'Lended count'
from UsersInfo 
where UsersInfo.MemberID in (
    select ToLend.UserID  'تعداد کتاب های قرض گرفته'  
    from ToLend
    inner join UsersInfo on ToLend.UserID = UsersInfo.MemberID
    group by UserID
    having count(UserID) > 2
)
```

Comment: yeeeeeeees, very very thanks Emanuele leoni, i want excatly this outputer

excuse me, could you please explain about your code, i don't understand how it work exactly

thanks bro

Comment: Hi @rezatajari , happy to help you. (select COUNT(userID) from ToLend ...) in SELECT returns the count of UsersInfo that is lended > 2. This subquery is necessary because you can't get this data in one only query. Let me know if I answered your question.

Comment: Yes bro, i understood now what is your mean, thanks a lot./

Answer (score 2):

You want the inner select to return a userid. Why do you add count() then ?

```
select  UsersInfo.fName 'نام', UsersInfo.lName 'نام خانوادگی' 
from UsersInfo 
where UsersInfo.MemberID in (
    select ToLend.UserID  'تعداد کتاب های قرض گرفته'  
    from ToLend
    inner join UsersInfo on ToLend.UserID = UsersInfo.MemberID
    group by UserID
    having count(UserID) > 2
)
```

Is MemberId a unique key within UsersInfo ?
If so you can change your query to:

```
select UsersInfo.fName 'نام', UsersInfo.lName 'نام خانوادگی' 
from UsersInfo 
where (select count()
         from ToLend
         where ToLend.UserID = UsersInfo.MemberID
      ) > 2
```

UPDATE: to get the count() in the output:

```
select UsersInfo.fName 'نام', UsersInfo.lName 'نام خانوادگی' , count()
  from UsersInfo 
 inner join ToLend
 where ToLend.UserID = UsersInfo.MemberID
 group by UsersInfo.MemberID, UsersInfo.fName, UsersInfo.lName
having count() > 2
```

I had to add `UsersInfo.MemberID` to the group by as I'm not sure if the combination `fName` + `lName` is unique. If so, you can leave out the `UsersInfo.MemberID` from the group by.

Comment: wow, that's very shorter than me.
thanks bro
but my question about other thing

i want show counter of UserID by count function in a column separate

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify your code as below

```
SELECT UsersInfo.fName 'نام'
    ,UsersInfo.lName 'نام خانوادگی'
    ,a.UserId 'تعداد کتاب های قرض گرفته'
    ,a.[cnt]
FROM UsersInfo u
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(ToLend.UserID) [cnt]
        ,ToLend.UserID
    FROM ToLend
    INNER JOIN UsersInfo ON ToLend.UserID = UsersInfo.MemberID
    GROUP BY UserID
    HAVING count(UserID) > 2
    ) a ON a.UserID = u.MemberId
```